# How to line up text and textboxes horizontally?

Tags: html, forms, html-table

[image]

This is what the following code produces. Could someone please help me make the text line up with the textboxes on all screen sizes? Originally I wanted to set the height of each text to line it up with the textboxes, but then realized it wouldn't be lined up on different sized screens. Any help is appreciated.

```
<body>

<h1>Contact Us</h1>

<p>Please take a few moments to fill out our feedback form. It will help us to better     address your needs. Thank you.</p>

<div id="mainLeft">
<table border="0" style="z-index: 1; position: inline; width: 440px; height: 334px; left: 0px; top: 0px;" width="644">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height="40" scope="col" width="144"><strong><span class="style4"><span class="style5">Your Name:</span> &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
        <td height="269" rowspan="10" scope="col" width="267">
        <form action="send-form.php" id="form" method="post" name="form">
        <p><input id="name" name="name" size="35" type="text" value="" />        </p>

        <p><input id="email" maxlength="55" name="email" size="35" type="text" /></p>

        <p><input id="address" maxlength="55" name="address" size="35" type="text" /></p>

        <p><input id="city" maxlength="55" name="city" size="35" type="text" /></p>

        <p><input id="state" maxlength="55" name="state" size="15" type="text" /></p>

        <p><input id="zip" maxlength="55" name="zip" size="25" type="text" /></p>

        <p><input id="telephone" maxlength="55" name="telephone" size="35" type="text" /></p>

        <p><input id="fax" maxlength="55" name="fax" size="35" type="text" /></p>

        <p><input id="feedback" maxlength="55" name="feedback" size="35" type="text" /></p>

        <p><textarea cols="30" id="comments" name="comments" rows="7" wrap="virtual"></textarea></p>
        <input name="Submit" onclick="MM_validateForm('email','','RisEmail','phone','','NisNum','comments','','R');ret​urn document.MM_returnValue" tabindex="1" type="submit" value="Submit" />&nbsp;</form>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td height="0" scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">Email Address: &nbsp;</span><br /></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="0" scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">Mailing Address: &nbsp;</span><br /></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="0" scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">City: &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="0" scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">State: &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="0" scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">Zip Code: &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="0" scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">Telephone: &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="0"scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">Fax: &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td height="0" scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">How did you hear about us?: &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
    </tr>

        <td scope="col"><span class="style6"><strong>Explanation of your legal situation: </strong></span><strong><span class="style4">&nbsp;</span></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" height="35">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `table`s are for tabular data, not forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need tables here, but you can take a look at example below how to do this:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>Contact Us</h1>

        <p>Please take a few moments to fill out our feedback form. It will help us to better     address your needs. Thank you.</p>

        <div id="mainLeft">
            <form action="send-form.php" id="form" method="post" name="form">
            <table border="0" style="z-index: 1; position: inline; width: 440px; height: 334px; left: 0px; top: 0px;" width="644">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col" width="144"><strong><span class="style4"><span class="style5">Your Name:</span> &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
                        <td><input id="name" name="name" size="35" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">Email Address: &nbsp;</span><br /></strong></td>
                        <td><input id="email" maxlength="55" name="email" size="35" type="text" /></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">Mailing Address: &nbsp;</span><br /></strong></td>
                        <td><input id="address" maxlength="55" name="address" size="35" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">City: &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
                        <td><input id="city" maxlength="55" name="city" size="35" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">State: &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
                        <td><input id="state" maxlength="55" name="state" size="15" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col"><strong><span class="style6">Zip Code: &nbsp;</span></strong></td>
                        <td><input id="zip" maxlength="55" name="zip" size="25" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Proper way to do this is:

```
<label for="test">Test</label>
<input type="text" name="test"/><br/>
```

Take a search/read some CSS tutorial to properly format your html.
Hope this help! :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This worked out well, even though it caused some stuff next to the form to move below it, but I think I can figure out a fix for that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use tables for that... use something as simple as:

```
<label for="name">Your name:</label><input type="text" name="name" /><br />
<label for="email">Email address:</label><input type="text" name="email" /><br />
```

etc...

You might not even need the line breaks (`<br />`s) if you style everything properly with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a label with the `for` attribute.

This example would actually place a label next to your text field.

```
<label for="myField">foo</label>
<input type="text" name="myField" id="myField" />
```

You don't need table here.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's going nuts seeing tables for a form, but forgot to answer your question: A css property called `vertical-align` can be played around with to get everything aligned. In my example, I've set it to 'top'. But you can use pixels (positive and negative values) to change the alignment as well. e.g `vertical-align: 1px;` or `vertical-align:-1px;`

Anyways, You shouldn't use tables for this (especially the way you're using them). You can achieve the same thing quite simply using divs/spans/etc:

**HTML** (snippet from your attached code)

```
<form action="send-form.php" id="form" method="post" name="form">
    <div class="fields">
        <label>Your name:</label>
        <span><input id="name" name="name" size="35" type="text" value="" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="fields">
        <label>Email Address:</label>
        <span><input id="email" maxlength="55" name="email" size="35" type="text" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="fields">
        <label>Comments:</label>
        <span><textarea></textarea></span>
    </div>    
</form>
```

**CSS** to style the above

```
.fields {width: 500px;}
.fields > label { display:inline-block; width:150px; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:top; }
.fields > span { display: inline-block; }
```

**Preview**: http://jsfiddle.net/JESqY/5/